# SIP: UAC UAC role change due to re-invite

Tags: sip, voip

As i understand it the UAC is defined as the entity that creates a new request, and UAS as the entity that repsonds to that request.

In the event of a UAS creating and sending a re-invite for an existing session, does it then take over the role of UAC?

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR, Yes, a SIP endpoint can be a User Agent Client/Server, the role is assumed during the `INVITE` transaction (i-e request-response).

About your example, (re-)`INVITE` is just an `INVITE` invoked inside an existing dialog created by a out-of-dialog/initial `INVITE` ; both are `INVITE` methods by the way and thus the client is the emiter of `INVITE` and the receiver is then the server.

Another common example is a SIP phone ; A telephone is a UAC when it sends an `INVITE` creating a new dialog but also a UAS because it accepts `INVITE` requests in order to ring the telephone.  One can say a SIP phone is by nature a *User Agent Client Server* - UACS.

The general and more abstract definition is around those lines, if a user-agent has dual roles UAS and UAC then the role is switch from one to the other during the coresponding transaction. In term of SIP protocol, UAC and UAS roles are logical only and an entity role is relevant during current transaction.

However, it is possible to have SIP entities which are only UAC or UAS, one use-case is notification where an entity is sending `NOTIFY` (UAC) and another is only receiving `NOTIFY` (UAS).

At that point we may conclude that client/server roles are valid only during a transaction.
Perfectly true from a Protocol perspective but not in the pratical case of B2BUA where two UAC/UAS are acting at the same time for the same invoked method but on two separated transactions. To be fair, B2BUA was not part of SIP RFCs.